# Find shortest path between points and plot on a map using leaflet package

Tags: r, leaflet, shortest-path

Friends, I have three shapefiles: the first refers to the location of 35 properties (they are in the form of points). Second is the area of ​​interest (polygon), and lastly the highway of this location. I would like to use the leaflet package to find the shortest path between these points or between one point and another, but shown on a map that I think can be provided by that package. . It is possible ?? If so, could you give me an example of how to do this.

Thank you!

```
library(geosphere)
#database
df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), Latitude = c(-23.2, -23.6, -23.9, -23.9, -23.6,  -23.5, -23.9, -23.9, -23.6, -23.9), 
Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.4, -49.3, -49.9, -49.3, -49.2, -49.6, -49.9)), class="data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -10L))

#clusters
d<-as.dist(distm(df[,2:1]))
fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
clusters<-cutree(fit.average, 4) 

#Scatter Plot
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
g<-ggplot(df, aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude, color=factor(clusters)))+ geom_point()
```

Comment: Hi! The question is really vague, could you include more details? For example: are you working with street networks or you just want to match each point with its closest neighbour? If you are working with street networks, what's the desired mode of transport? Could you include some data?

Comment: Thanks friend. I improved the question, could you have a look please? Basically I want to find the shortest route between one point or another, considering the local highway, but I would like to show this on a map.

Comment: Agila, was I able to express a little better what I want to do?

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry but it's still a very generic question. Neverthless, I think you could use [sfnetworks](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/), [dodgr](https://atfutures.github.io/dodgr/) or [stplanr](https://docs.ropensci.org/stplanr/). Check the corresponding vignettes and maybe add a more detailed example with some data.